# What is the price of a shield?

Tags: dnd-5e, armor, shield

What is the price of a shield?

I have looked in the Player Handbook and I can't seem to find any specifics relating to the price of a shield.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### A shield costs 10 GP

It is listed on the Armor table. It's at the bottom, below plate which is the last entry for Heavy Armor.

It's on Basic Rules page 46, or Player's Handbook page 145.